# Do all the McBain clips in The Simpsons form a film when pieced together?

Tags: the-simpsons

I was told before that all the McBain clips on The Simpsons, though they may seem independent, when pieced together actually make a full film where each clip follows on from the previous one.

I've looked on YouTube but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Funny or Die pieced all the clips together and can be seen here and they do make one long clip:

From FoD

> McBain from the Simpsons is actually a full length film when you put them all together.

Comment: "10 times more addictive than marijuana!" Haha, what a great movie.

Comment: If you want to embed it in the post, here's a YouTube version. https://youtu.be/BzjfrdcN1Z8